# No deselect event for tagfield?

Tags: extjs

Can somebody explain why there's only beforedeselect event but not "deselect" or "afterdeselect"?

Is there a way to get around this limitation? I need to execute code everytime an item is deselected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TagField extends from Combobox.

Inside the `Ext.form.field.ComboBox` listeners are added to the `selectionModel`.
These include only `beforeselect` and `beforedeselect`, but not select.
The beforedeselect is fired inside the `onBeforeDeselect` method.

If you want to add it you have to override `onBindStore` and `createPicker`.

The selectionModel is extended from `Ext.selection.DataViewModel`. You can find all events there.

Example (just wrote it down you have to complete it):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.form.field.ComboBox', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',

    onBindStore: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        const me = this,
              picker = me.picker;
        
        if (picker) {
            me.pickerSelectionModel.on({
                scope: me,
                deselect: me.onDeselect,
                afterdeselect: me.onAfterDeselect
            });
        }
    },

    onDeselect: Ext.emptyFn,
    onAfterDeselect: Ext.emptyFn
});
```